# I am trying to write down the definition of a random variable and its probability mass function

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

Given the definition below, I'd like to translate it to language of functions to make it easier to deal with:

> Parameter: integers $a, b; a \le b$
>
> Experiment: pick one of $a, a+1, a+2 \ldots, b$ at random; all equally likely
>
> Sample Space: $\{a, a+1, \ldots, b\}$
>
> Random Variable $X: X(w) = w$

From the givens it looks like random variable is $X: [\text {domain here}] \to \{a, a+1, \ldots, b\}$ as $X(w) = w$ and its PMF is $P_X: \{a, a+1, \ldots, b\} \to [\text {codomain or range here}]$ given as $[\text {rule here}]$. How can I fill in the missing bits granted the rest makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each $i \in \{a, \dots,b\} $ you have

$P_X (i) = P(\{ \omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) = i\}) = \dfrac{1}{b-a} $

Comment: @ Liad, soory I deleted my first question(thought it was too inane), didn't expect your answer so fast. One more question: what's the domain of $X$ granted its codomain and the rule it's given by are correct? Thanks.

Comment: The domain of X is the sample space. $X:\Omega \to R$ and $P_X : Im(X) \to \{ \dfrac{1}{b-a}\}$